# How to replace some colored characters with blank sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I am trying to replace some sequence of character with a blank. But I am not able to replace it.

File name is **Test**:

```
id       ^[[0mevent^[[0m            ^[[0msuite^[[0m                                     ^[[0mok^[[0m     ^[[0mnok^[[0m    ^[[0mskip^[[0m  test  up        owner     du     duplex  type   stp             inst_type  prep  created              finished
```

I am trying to replace `^[[0m` with a blank character. To do so I am using the following command to achieve the aforementioned task.

```
sed 's/\^\[\[0m//g' Test
```

However, the above command is having not impact.

The problem is due to coloured font.

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: [Here, it does remove them](http://ideone.com/PSh15G).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I was using O instead of 0.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the text has color, maybe because of it I am not able to replace it with blank. Your commands work for normal text but colored text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following command to replace the colored text:

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" abc
```

Source: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed

Comment: Really `[m|K]`? Do you know what it matches?

Comment: `M`, `K` or a `|`. Check *regex character class* notion on the Web.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing it with `z` just remove the `z` also instead of 0 seems that you have typed big `O`. Change it to `0` then it will work very well:

```
~$ echo "id       ^[[0mevent^[[0m            ^[[0msuite^[[0m"|sed 's/\^\[\[0m//g'
id       event            suite
```

Comment: Sorry i am replacing it with blank. z was a typo

Comment: @JohnRambo Checkout the edit.

Comment: text has some font color, that's why I am not able to replace it with blank

Comment: These are not literal characters in your case. Kasra's regex does not really help. Just use the solution from the original answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yup, I realized that